# parseLine(String nextLine, boolean multi) in opencsv

Tags: opencsv

I am learning opencsv now,the method parseLine(String nextLine, boolean multi) in CSVParser is a little complex. What is    the  mearning  of the field 'inField' in the class CSVParser? What does 'inQuotes' and 'fromQuotedField'  denote in method  parseLine(String nextLine, boolean multi); Thanks!

about line 112 in CSVParser : private boolean inField = false ;

about 348 line in  parseLine(String nextLine, boolean multi):

```
    boolean inQuotes = false;
    boolean fromQuotedField = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The inQuotes tells the parser that the data it is reading is inside a quoted string - so if a delemeter character is met then it is part of the string instead of a signal to start a new field.

inField has basically the same functionality but it is a global variable (and it is not dependent on quotations).  The reason openCSV needs to know this is that the CSVReader feeds the one line at a time - so if there is a line feed inside one of the fields then it will take multiple calls to the CSVParser to build one complete record.  Hence the parseLineMulti.

The fromQuoteFields is a new addition for [feature request #60](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/feature-requests/60/).  This is used with the null field indicator to detect if you have a set of empty quotes should the field be an empty string or null.